# Forcing Pytorch to use GPU

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I've recently followed a tutorial here: https://www.provideocoalition.com/automatic-rotoscopingfor-free/

And ended with a functional bit of code that generated masks outlining interesting objects.

But now, I want to run it on my GPU, since the CPU is way too slow.

I have CUDA installed and all, but Pytorch refuses to use it. I've used most tricks like setting torch.device and all, but not available; Pytorch keeps using 0 GPU.

Here's the code:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import torch
    import torchvision.transforms as T
    from torchvision import models
    import numpy as np
    
    fcn = None
    
    
    device = torch.device('cuda')
    torch.cuda.set_device(0)
    print('Using device:', device)
    print()
    
    if device.type == 'cuda':
        print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
        print('Memory Usage:')
        print('Allocated:', round(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')
        print('Cached:', round(torch.cuda.memory_cached(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')
    
    
    def getRotoModel():
        global fcn
        #fcn = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet101(pretrained=True).eval()
        fcn = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True).eval()
    
    
    # Define the helper function
    def decode_segmap(image, nc=21):
    
        label_colors = np.array([(0, 0, 0),  # 0=background
                               # 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
                   (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128),
                   # 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
                   (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0),
                   # 11=dining table, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
                   (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128),
                   # 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
                   (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)])
    
        r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
        b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
    
        for l in range(0, nc):
            idx = image == l
            r[idx] = label_colors[l, 0]
            g[idx] = label_colors[l, 1]
            b[idx] = label_colors[l, 2]
    
        rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
        return rgb
    
    def createMatte(filename, matteName, size):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        trf = T.Compose([T.Resize(size),
                         T.ToTensor(), 
                         T.Normalize(mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                     std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
        inp = trf(img).unsqueeze(0)
        if (fcn == None): getRotoModel()
        out = fcn(inp)['out']
        om = torch.argmax(out.squeeze(), dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()
        rgb = decode_segmap(om)
        im = Image.fromarray(rgb)
        im.save(matteName)
```

What could I do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you move any tensor to GPU (by using `.cuda()`) or created one on the GPU?

Comment: mh i don't think this code does that ? if i understood, tensors are like GPU matrixes, so i should rewrite all the numpy arrays as cuda tensors ? because i think that means rewriting the whole thing

Comment: what do you mean by it refuses to use cuda but it keeps using GPU 0? if it's using GPU 0 it's also using cuda. Are you instead looking for multi-gpu support? for example `nn.DataParallel`?

Comment: @jodag sorry. By "using 0 GPU" meant, not using any gpu at all. Sorry! My gpu shows up when I run get_device_name but I can tell from the time it takes and the windows perf thing that the GPU is idle

Comment: Try the following. In `getRotoModel()` add the line `fcn.cuda()` to the end and change `fcn(inp)['out']` to `fcn(inp.cuda())['out']`. If you want to use the GPU you need to move the model and input tensor to the GPU.

Comment: some progress! now i get CUDA out of memory (which is ludicrous, but progress still). What do you mean by your last line ? do you mean "do the changes i explained above" ?

Comment: yes it's just an explaination of why we need to use `.cuda` in those locations.

Comment: awwwww you solved my problem but apparently my gpu has too little memory :( or maybe everything isn't allocated (CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 58.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.49 GiB already allocated; 17.90 MiB free; 173.79 MiB cached)), even if i have nothing using the gpu. THanks tho, edit your comment an i'll mark it as the solution

Comment: What was the issue? Did you just not have any code which would actually use the GPU?

Comment: @AMC exactly. It was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is set up correctly you just have to move the tensors you want to process on the gpu to the gpu. You can try this to make sure it works in general

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor([1.0]) # create tensor with just a 1 in it
t = t.cuda() # Move t to the gpu
print(t) # Should print something like tensor([1], device='cuda:0')
print(t.mean()) # Test an operation just to be sure
```

You already have a `device` variable so instead of `.cuda()` you can just use `.to(device)`. Which is also the preferable way to do it so you can just switch between cpu and gpu by setting one variable.

Comment: so i'd need to rewrite most, if not all of my file right ? i hoped there would have been a "compute everything on the gpu" switch

Comment: You don't really need to rewrite everything. Just add some `.to(device)` From looking at the code it might be enough to do it for the `inp` tensor and for the `fcn` model. So the network will be run on the gpu. I guess that is the part taking the longest to compute on CPU.